# In android 12/13 Is possible delete file in Media.store (picture) , writed by other app?

Tags: android, delete-file, mediastore

I´m using pictures and videos saved by other app in "Pictures" folder, and copied/imported in myApp files zone.
I want this files be removed from "Pictures" after copying to my app.
Is possible this throught Media.store and resolver.delete(Uri...) ? I get a permission problem.

com.xxx.xxx has no access to content://media/external/images/media/1000000026

But i don´t know what permission to ask.......write_external_storage is not valid from A11

Regards.

Comment: Not using the MediaStore.delete(). But have a look at createDeleteIntent().